# Problem with Zend Framework and UTF-8 characters (æøå)

Tags: php, zend-framework, utf-8

Hope here are some with more knowledge about Zend Framework than me, I've been trying to search for the answer but I'm not able to fin anything anywhere.

**Problem:**

When adding the content of a Zend_Form to the database with the use of Zend_Db the characters æ ø å  is replaced by Ã¸Ã¦Ã¥

**System**

- WampServer 2.0i

  - Apache 2.2.11
  - MySQL 5.1.36
  - PHP 5.3.0
- Zend Framework 1.10.0

**Modifications done to make it work (which it does not)**

application.ini

```
resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "//Brukernavn//"
resources.db.params.password = "//Passord//"
resources.db.params.dbname = "//Database//"
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
resources.db.params.driver_options.1002 = "SET NAMES utf8"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
```

To all forms I've added

```
->setAttrib('accept-charset', 'utf-8');
```

And in Bootstrap.php I've placed the following code:

```
$view->setEncoding('UTF-8');
$view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');
$view->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-Type', 'text/html;charset=utf-8');
```

The database is set to utf8_general_ci

Anyone have a tip on how to get it to work?

**Soulution:**

It's a bug in PHP 5.3.0 and 5.3.1 ( http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47224
) so I choose to downgrade to 5.2.11, and all worked like a charm.

Thanks to Pekka and Greg K for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listening to your description, the data departs from the form as UTF-8. Could it be that your *database tables themselves* are still `latin1`?

Comment: I believe he said the database is set to `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: Oh yeah, overread that. Still, the tables and their columns need to be utf-8 too (just converting the db isn't enough). If he confirms the tables and columns are UTF-8, I'll delete this answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Actually I had forgotten to convert the fields themself, but no change in behavior after doing so.

Comment: Just a hack, can you try manually running `"SET NAMES utf8"` as a query before you insert the data? Then you'd at least know that the connection is the problem.

Comment: So when you connect to your MySQL database and type `\s` you see:

    Server characterset: utf8
    Db     characterset: utf8
    Client characterset: utf8
    Conn.  characterset: utf8 (assuming `SET NAMES utf8` was issued)

?

Comment: Running "SET NAMES utf8" did the tric.

Comment: All right! Then something's wrong with the database parameters. I don't know enough about Zend to know how to fix them. Anyone?

Comment: Thanks for your help.

You got me on the right trac, it's a bug in PHP 5.3.0 and 5.3.1
http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47224

Thanks again.

Comment: @Christian Frøystad: You're welcome, and thanks for the link! That is very good to know.

Comment: also, setting collation values is something different. utf8_general_ci refers to the way the data is sorted, not how it is stored. Configuring the client is more important.

Answer (score 1):

Solution that worked for me:

All of the above database things, plus adding the UTF-8 encoding headMeta tag to the layout.

So, layout.phtml looks like this:

```
<?php echo $this->doctype() ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
       <?php echo $this->headMeta(); ?> <!-- This one does the trick! -->       
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?> 
    </body>
</html>
```

And Bootstrap.php like this:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{

    protected function _initDoctype()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('view');
        $view = $this->getResource('view');
        $view->setEncoding('UTF-8');
        $view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');
        $view->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-Type', 'text/html;charset=utf-8');
    }

}
```

Now swedish chars like åäö display correctly, and, although not tried, I think chinese or whatever will as well.

Answer (score 0):

use htmlentities($val) to output values encoded

Comment: this did not work for me because it simply converts the wrong characters to the html entity version

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me turned out to be that I had a decorator using [`htmlentities()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) which defaults to `ISO-8859-1` encoding if not specified, instead of `UTF-8` for versions of PHP >= 5.4.

Answer (score 0):

In function _initDatabase() must be add the following code.

```
$db->getConnection()->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

You can reference this here: http://osdir.com/ml/php.zend.framework.db/2008-04/msg00012.html

Answer (score 0):

i have the same issue in my site, i resolved this issue by adding the charset in application.ini file.

here i add the following codes.

```
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
resources.db.params.driver_options.1002 = "SET NAMES utf8"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
```